Jira Insights: Project Settings -> Estimation Method
I am attempting to use the "Insights" feature on my sprint board. I get the following error after clicking "Insights":
*We don’t currently support your estimation setting. This insight only supports story points, issue count, or time estimation.
*
I have the following options in my project's Estimation Method dropdown menu when I go to Configure Board:

QA Story Point Estimate
Original time estimate
Dev Story Point Estimate
Resolution Attempts
Time Spent on RCA
Timebox (in days)
Total Story Point Estimate
Issue Count

When I select "QA Story Point Estimate" then the insights work. But that's only half the picture. I need the full estimate (both Dev and QA estimates). This is the only option from the dropdown menu that works to populate the Insights charts. Why? How can I get this to work with the Total Story Point Estimate option?
I expect that when I select "Total Story Point Estimate" that the charts would populate. Instead, it just gives me an error.
